# Django - How to take string values on URL for PUT?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I set up my URL like this :

```
path('voucher/<str:voucher_id>', views.update_voucher),
```

My process

```
def update_voucher(request, voucher_id):
    put = QueryDict(request.body)
    try: 
        customer_id = put.get('customer_id')
    except: 
        return HttpResponse("Missing parameters")
    updateVoucher = Voucher.objects.filter(code = voucher_id)
```

Its a `PUT` call taking parameters from both `body` and `url`.  (voucher_id from `URL`) and (customer_id from `body`)
.

I call this URL `http://127.0.0.1:5448/voucher/NewVoucher`

I got this error:

```
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'NewVoucher'.
```

The below is my model:
here.

```
class Voucher(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    delivery_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    start_at = models.DateTimeField()
    end_at = models.DateTimeField()
    discount_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    discount_amount = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

P/S: I am a maintainer - cant change method function, and cant change the way this `URL` take parameters from both `URL` and `body`

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing voucher_id as integers. instead you are passing code "NewVoucher" which is a string as per this error.

```
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'NewVoucher'.
```

You have to pass id in integers so it would look something like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:5448/voucher/1
```

So far as i've understood you are looking for filter based on voucher code i,e "NewVoucher".
then Your method should be changed as,

```
def update_voucher(request, voucher_code, *args, **kwargs):
    voucher = get_object_or_404(Voucher, code=voucher_code)
    customer_id = request.data.get("customer_id")  # im not sure where you are using this customer_id
    if not customer_id:
        raise HttpResponse("Missing parameters")
    # updateVoucher = Voucher.objects.filter(code = voucher_id) no need of this line as voucher variable contains it


# urls
path('voucher/<str:voucher_code>', views.update_voucher),
```

Comment: appreciate it, however, my `voucher_code` is not an `int` but a `varchar`, its should like this `voucher123`, `abcdef123`

Comment: yes you can use that now as per the solution ive given.

Comment: `ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'NewVoucher'.` this is also because the primary key of voucher model is id field so it expects you to pass id instead of string/varchar. you can either change pk key or use the solution ive given. both works